# delphi action manager shortcut for +,-, enter for actions

Tags: delphi, keyboard-shortcuts, delphi-7

im working on **delphi 7**, and i have an applicaton where im using a **action manager** for creating actions and then assigning them shortcuts
the shortcuts in action manager are already defined in the **shortcut** property..but i want to have a shortcut like

```
 1. ADD ,that is the + on the numpad
 2. Subtract key ,that is the - on the numpad
 3. divide key  , that is the / on the numpad.
 4. enter key
```

i tried assigning my own shortcut as **subtract** and **ADD** but it gives me this error message
[image]

i also tried - but nothing is happening

my code to track the action

```
  var
      Action : TBasicAction;
      begin
        Action := Sender as TBasicAction;
       if (Action is TAction) and not TAction(Action).Enabled then   exit;
      case Action.tag of
        1                  :         ShowMessage('ADD + pressed');
        2                  :         ShowMessage ('divide / pressed');
        3                  :         ShowMessage ('subtract - pressed');
        4                  :         ShowMessage ('enter pressed');
      end;

   end;
```

i can use the normal

```
   **GetKeyState(VK_ADD) AND 128)=128;** OR **GetKeyState(VK_return) AND 128)=128;**
```

to find it the keys are pressed
in keypress or keydown event but  i want to use the action manager shortcuts

Comment: I would think that the fact that 'subtract' and 'add' are not in the dropdownlist of the ShortCut property would be enough hint that you cannot use them as shortcuts? At least not through the action/actionmanager framework...

Comment: I think you can't use short cuts for this and will have to use key events. You can always do Action.Execute. Be aware that most computers sold today don't have the keys that you are describing.

Comment: @David, define "most". I have two laptops that both have full numeric keypads, a third that has no keypad but when `FN` is used to enable the embedded one has the above keys, three desktops (2 home, 1 office) that all have the full numeric keypad including those keys. One laptop is recent (6 months), and the work desktop was brand new two months ago.

Comment: @ken I mean most sold as opposed to most bought by you! ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can assign them at runtime:

```
Action1.ShortCut := menus.ShortCut(VK_ADD, []);
Action2.ShortCut := menus.ShortCut(VK_SUBTRACT, []);
```

Comment: Starting from your answer I was able to use `Menus.ShortCutToText` to work out how to do this at design time!

Comment: @sertac its giving me error 'Undeclared identifier: 'ShortCut''

Comment: @Presley, include 'menus' to in your uses clause.

Answer (score 7):

These keys have the following special names which can be assigned directly through the `ShortCut` property in the Object Inspector.

- NUM ADD
- NUM SUB
- NUMMULT
- /

I'm not sure about the numpad <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. I don't know if it has a special name or indeed if it can be distinguished from the normal <kbd>Enter</kbd> key using a shortcut.

**Update**

It turns out that the names for these keys vary from machine to machine. François points out that the names come from the [`GetKeyNameText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646300%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Windows API function, for which the documentation points out:

> The format of the key-name string depends on the current keyboard layout. The keyboard driver maintains a list of names in the form of character strings for keys with names longer than a single character. The key name is translated according to the layout of the currently installed keyboard, thus the function may give different results for different input locales.

For example, Sertac found that on his system, the names are `NUM +`, `NUM -` etc.

I generated the values by calling `ShortcutToText` and you could do the same to generate names appropriate for your system.

Comment: The first three generate the "Invalid property value" mentioned in the original post (D2007 and XE). The last one doesn't differentiate between the numpad and normal keypad `/` keys, at least on D2007.

Comment: I guess these should be a recent addition, does not work here with D2007. Weird thing, '/' also gives invalid property here.

Comment: @David & @Sertac: Actually, it does not depend on XE vs XE2 but on what `GetKeyNameText` (user32 API) returns. See code in `{Vcl.}Menus. GetSpecialName` or play with `GetKeyNameText(Message.KeyData...` in a `WMKeyDown` message handler. But once set in the OI, it's converted to the right number anyway so it shouldn't be a problem at runtime.

Comment: Oh, and even if `Num Enter` is the special name for the numpad Enter, it is not accepted as a shortcut, because it has the same scan code as the regular `Enter` (only with the Extended-key flag on bit 27) .

Comment: @david..num +, num - is working but num * or / is not working

Comment: Combine sertac's approach with the output from ShortcutToText to work out the other keys. As Francois explains, the names are machine dependent

Comment: Ok, I see Delphi 7 is missing the shortcut function. Will need to think about that.

Comment: @David - D3 has the ShortCut and ShortCutToText functions, but there's a bug in 'GetSpecialName' function (it passes a 256 byte buffer to GetKeyNameText but checks for a 1 byte return), so 'ShortCutToText' is not working for some keys. I guess that's also the case for D7. And I guess that's the reason OP has accepted the other answer..

Comment: D7 isn't missing the `ShortCut` function; it's in `Menus.pas`.

Comment: @Ken Thank you. That has become clear now. When Presley commented on Sertac's answer that the code resulted in the error `'Undeclared identifier: 'ShortCut''` then that seemed to be the explanation. Clearly Presley was not using Sertac's code and had omitted the `menus.` part of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just make up names for keys and expect the Object Inspector to know what you mean. The `ShortCut` property isn't a string; it's a `TShortCut`, and can only be assigned a value that can be converted to a `TShortCut`.

There are no keys on the keyboard named `ADD`, `subtract`, or `divide`, and so they can't be assigned as such to a `ShortCut`; they don't exist, so they can't be converted to a `TShortCut`.

You can set the shortcut directly to <kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>/</kbd>, and <kbd>Enter</kbd> (the values `+`, `-`, `/`, and `Enter`), and they should work fine. (Although assignment of common single keystrokes is usually not a good idea - if the form only has a single thing it can do in response to the `+` key, it might be fine; if there's an edit control or something that could also receive a `+` key sensibly then it's a terrible idea because the shortcut's action might fire when the user didn't intend it to do so).

As David points out, this won't pick up the number keypad part of the requirement. For that, you'll have to assign the `ShortCut` in code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AddAction.ShortCut := Shortcut(VK_ADD, []);
  SubtractAction.ShortCut := ShortCut(VK_SUBTRACT, []);
  DivideAction.ShortCut := ShortCut(VK_DIVIDE, []);
end;
```

I can't find any way to differentiate between the NUMPAD Enter and the regular enter using virtual key definitions, though. You may need to do that with a modifier or in the keypress events.

As far as figuring out which one was used, you should be naming them appropriately (as in `AddAction`, `SubtractAction`, `DivideAction`, and `EnterAction`), and then you can actually reference them by name in the `OnUpdate` or `OnExecute` events:

```
if (Sender = TAddAction) then // Add keypress fired
  DoAddAction
else if (Sender = TSubtractAction) then
  DoSubtractAction
// etc
```

Comment: This won't single out numpad. Also, T prefix should be used on types.

Comment: Sender is an object reference, `TAddAction` sounds like it should be a type but since you are comparing with equality operator I presume that `TAddAction` is not a type. I guess you meant to write `AddAction` instead.

Comment: @David, what types are you referring to? The only thing I can see you might object to is `ShortCut` in the last line of the second paragraph, and it's a reference to a property name, not a type. You're right about numpad, though; those keys can't be assigned in the OI. Editing. Thanks for that correction.

Comment: Ah, got it. Missed that one. (Was changing my last comment to respond to your second point when you posted the last one.)

Comment: Those keys can be assigned in OI, as per my answer inspired by Sertac

Comment: @KenWhite its giving me an error 'Undeclared identifier: 'ShortCut''

Comment: @PrestleyDias: Sorry; add `Menus` to your uses clause. (I tested with a menu just because it was much quicker than with actions.) See the [docs here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Menus.ShortCut)